# R Running a GLM with warnings

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

I am currently in a kaggle contest for learning purposes
I am trying to run a GLM on data using caret and cross validation

```
# Add X Validation to the mix to see if it improves model performance
library ("caret")

# Cross Validation
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     number = 10, 
                     savePredictions = TRUE)

mod1 <- train(target ~ .,  data=train, 
              method="glm", family="binomial", 
               trControl = ctrl, tuneLength = 5)
```

When i run the analysis i get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

I have searched google all morning and it seems this warning can be brought up for a number of reasons

- There are `NAs` in the training set. I ran `sum(is.na(train))` and got 0 as the result
- Too many independent variables `dim(train)` brings up [1] 8161   25

I looked into the function with the code `body(predict.lm)` and found the code below but when i run those tests everything seems to be ok

```
if (p < ncol(X) && !(missing(newdata) || is.null(newdata))) 
  warning("prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading")
```

Can anyone help?
I can provide semi anomized data if you think it will help.

### DATA

```
   VAR1           AGE           VAR2           VAR3       
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :16.00   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : 0.00  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:39.00   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.: 9.00  
 Median :0.0000   Median :45.00   Median :0.0000   Median :11.00  
 Mean   :0.1711   Mean   :44.79   Mean   :0.7212   Mean   :10.49  
 3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:51.00   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:13.00  
 Max.   :4.0000   Max.   :81.00   Max.   :5.0000   Max.   :23.00  

 VAR4       Var5        SEX               EDUCATION         VAR5      
 No :7084   Yes :4894   M  :3786   <High School :1203   9      :1825  
 Yes:1077   z_No:3267   F   :4375  Bachelors    :2242   2      :1271  
                                   Masters      :1658   7      :1117  
                                   PhD          : 728   6      : 988  
                                   High School:2330     5      : 835  
                                                        8      : 712  
                                                        (Other):1413  

VAR 6               VAR7             TYPE               HAS_INDIC   
Commercial:3029     Min.   : 1.000   A    :2145         no :5783  
Private   :5132     1st Qu.: 1.000   B    :676          yes:2378  
                    Median : 4.000   C    :1389             
                    Mean   : 5.351   D    :907             
                    3rd Qu.: 7.000   E    : 750             
                    Max.   :25.000   F    :2294             

    FREQ          IS_REL          VAR8          INDIC      
 Min.   :0.0000   No :7161   Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :-3.000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   Yes:1000   1st Qu.: 0.000   1st Qu.: 1.000  
 Median :0.0000              Median : 1.000   Median : 8.000  
 Mean   :0.7986              Mean   : 1.696   Mean   : 8.318  
 3rd Qu.:2.0000              3rd Qu.: 3.000   3rd Qu.:12.000  
 Max.   :5.0000              Max.   :13.000   Max.   :28.000  

SC              VAL              target       OCCUPY    
 Y:6492         Min.   :     0   0:6008       A :5729  
 N:1669         1st Qu.:     0   1:2153       B:2432  
                Median :160542                          
                Mean   :154580                          
                3rd Qu.:238256                          
                Max.   :885282                          

 TIME             BUCKET               COST   
 Min.   : 2.472   (-0.367,36.7]:2739   Min.   : 75.46  
 1st Qu.: 7.381   (36.7,73.4]  :2698   1st Qu.:190.67  
 Median : 9.489   (73.4,110]   :1600   Median :238.33  
 Mean   : 9.198   (110,147]    : 651   Mean   :239.23  
 3rd Qu.:11.266   (147,184]    : 280   3rd Qu.:286.79  
 Max.   :21.833   (184,220]    : 122   Max.   :526.17  
                  (Other)      :  71                   
 OLD_BUCKET 
 (-0.0057,0.285]:5547  
 (0.285,0.57]   : 927  
 (0.57,0.856]   : 741  
 (0.856,1.14]   : 278  
 (2.57,2.85]    :  74  
 (3.14,3.42]    :  70  
 (Other)        : 524
```

Comment: Data always helps. Did you have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it)? Rank deficiency often occurs when you have zero variance in some parts of the model.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `caret` but you're doing glm regression and the error message you're getting suggests you're trying to do prediction with linear regression. The conflict between the two would seem a likely candidate for your problem.

Comment: There's no way to really know without the data. I suspect that there is either a linear dependency in your data or some factor levels do not have any data available once you resample them.